# Does gcloud storage cp run in background?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was copying some files between two buckets on GCP using Coud Shell. The source bucket contained quite a lot files, like higher units of thousands. In the process of copying, I got message in the Cloud Shell that said that my cloud shell connection was disconnected. However, the log from the cp command was still running in the shell.

After a while, I ran `gsutil du -s` in another session and the contents of the source and destination bucket were the same.
So, does the `gcloud storage cp` command run in background? If so, is there some way I can check the status of the command?

Comment: The command likely just initiates a bucket-to-bucket copy

Comment: If the command takes too much time, spin up the smallest VM (not pre-emptible), and run your gcloud command in a nohup wrapper.